# If statement with an exception to a rule in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble using and if statement to create the following logic. I think it would be similar to a nested if statement in excel but I am not sure how to go about it in MySQL.

I have field called package, 2019 Price, and 2020 Price, State, and Segment.

For each transaction, if the "date" field =< 2019 use the "2019 Price" field, if the "date" field >= 2020 use the "2020 Price" field. As an exception to this rule, if the State = 'CO' and the Segment = 'promo', use "2019 Price" field.

I started writing an if statement below. I am just unsure how to add the exception to the rule:

```
IF(`Date` >= '2020-01-01', `2020 EFT`, `2019 EFT`) as `Price`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and added to my sql tool belt! Thank you!

Comment: And what is wrong with your code?  I would use `case`, but MySQL supports both.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE` to implement multiple conditions. It tests them in order, so you can put the exception first.

```
CASE WHEN State = 'CO' AND Segment = 'promo' THEN `2019 EFT`
     WHEN Date >= '2020-01-01' THEN `2020 EFT`
     ELSE `2019 EFT`
END AS Price
```

You could also combine conditions with `OR`.

```
IF(Date < '2020-01-01' OR (State = 'CO' AND Segment = 'promo'), `2019 EFT`, `2020 EFT`) AS Price
```

I recommend you always use parentheses when you combine `AND` and `OR` conditions, as the default precedence is not always what you expect.

Comment: Thank you I much appreciate your help! The only issue I am having with this is that if the "date" field is in year 2020, and State = 'CO' AND Segment = 'promo' it needs to pull over the "2019 Price" field, not "2020 Price" field.

Comment: That's what this should do. The first case that's true takes precedence.